# Why is the mass moment of inertia $I_x = 0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

How to derive Ix in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moment of inertia $I_x$ is zero here because the object does not occupy any space in the *yz* plane. If you were to consider the rod with radius $r>0$ then

$$ I_x = \tfrac{m}{2} r^2 $$
$$ I_y = \tfrac{m}{12} \ell^2 + \tfrac{m}{4} r^2$$

but since $r \ll \ell$, the above simplifies to

$$ I_x = 0 $$
$$ I_y = \tfrac{m}{12} \ell^2 $$

The interpretation is that there is no net torque about the *x* axis considered, because if there was it would result in infinite rotation acceleration about *x*.